# mediarecorder.setVideoSize() fails with maximum resolution

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I tried to find the camera resolution by

```
final Parameters p = this.camera.getParameters();
List<Size> previewSizes=p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```

and set the video size of media recorder by

```
this.mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(previewSizes.get(0).width, previewSizes.get(0).height);
```

I used to record video in Landscape mode.

`MediaRecorder` fails to record video with this high resolution.

When I try with less resolution, it is recording.

Is there a problem with screen display size and video size we are setting ?

Answer (score 6):

try something like this

getBestPreviewSize () will determine best possible resolution based on provided width and height. The is obviously missing the main mediarecorder and camera setup details but you can find them quite easily and you've probably already done that

```
...
    Camera.size size = getBestPreviewSize(720,480, mCamera.getParameters());

    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(size.width,size.height);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
...

  private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result=null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
            if (result==null) {
                result=size;
            } else {
                int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                int newArea=size.width*size.height;

                if (newArea>resultArea) {
                    result=size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return(result);
}
```